# Historical intraday data of currencies through Alpha Vantage api (Python)?

Tags: python

I am trying to download historical intraday data of USD/EURO for the last 6 months from alpha vantage

Here is the code I am trying to execute

```
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import 
api = "######"
ts = TimeSeries(key=####,output_format = "pandas")
data,metadata = ts.get_intraday(symbol = "USD/CAD",interval= "1min" , outputsize = "full")
print(data)
```

It is giving an error

```
ValueError: Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=USD/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY.
```

What can be the reason for this ?

Comment: There is an error on the second line, you haven't specified what to import.

Comment: @RobKwasowski You are absolutely right but in such a case the program will abort due to SyntaxError. Since the program has gone through I assumed it is a typing mistake. I am requesting the OP to fix the problem in line 2

Comment: @rohanpatni .. Please fix the second line by finishing your import statement ...  it is giving rise to confusion and your audience might think that the error is in line 2 .. Simple fix .. please do it .. Thank you

Comment: @rohanpatni When you say currency = "USD/CAD" .. most likely your formed API is wrong and due to "/" it is prematurely terminated. See the edited answer below. May be this will work.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation for [TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#intraday) and your error message it is somewhat apparent to me that your API is invalid. If you see your command the API is actually missing and as per the [documentation](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#intraday) it is required.

Try adding your API token/key in the last line (below) and **at least** the above problem should be solved.

```py
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import 
api = "######"
ts = TimeSeries(key=####,output_format = "pandas")
data,metadata = ts.get_intraday(function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY, symbol = "USD/CAD",interval= "1min" , outputsize = "full", apikey="Please fill your api key here")
```

Hope it helps.

**===============================================================**

**Edit after going through the source code of alphavantage.**

So I went through the code. There is nothing wrong in it as par as apikey is concerned. Since in the line before, where you actually call the api, you have instantiated the TimeSeries class  and at that time you have given the api key. So it is not needed again.

I could replicate your error at my end. After some traversal through code, I realised that you are passing the wrong currency perhaps. It should not be **USD/CAD** but just **USD**. If you rather wish to get for USD/CAD .. you have to say **USDCAD**. When you say currency = "USD/CAD" .. most likely your formed API is wrong and due to "/" it is prematurely terminated.

Below is the edited code. I have also edited your original post and in the second line, after import, I have added TimeSeries. I hope that is right. If not please reject the edit.

```py
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
api = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
ts = TimeSeries(key=api,output_format = "pandas")
data,metadata = ts.get_intraday(symbol = "USD",interval= "1min" , outputsize = "full")
print(data)
data,metadata = ts.get_intraday(symbol = "USDCAD",interval= "1min" , outputsize = "full")
print(data)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The OP has kept it secret .. I think it is intentional. He can't let everybody know the api :-)

Comment: correct Amit, is historical data of currencies available to download through this API ?

Comment: @RobKwasowski I see what you are saying. Yes he has .. I was for some reasons focussed on third line. Upvoted your comment

Comment: @rohanpatni .. That I don't know .. if it is available but I spotted the error about missing apikey and so I posted. You will know it better. I have not used it. I am sorry

Comment: @rohanpatni .. Yes it is .. Please click this link provided in the docs .. A well formatted string is giving the output .. https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo

Comment: Please let me know if my guesstimate solution was right or wrong. Will learn something about this api.

Comment: @Amit, thanks. I am getting data of usdcad now, but it is just coming from 5th Jan to 10th Jan.  How can I get for complete 2019 ?

Comment: @rohanpatni I don't think there is an option for complete 2019 using Intraday. However as per the documentation you can get 20+ years of historical data using Daily. In such a case however your data will be limited to (date, daily open, daily high, daily low, daily close, daily volume) for every entry. Having said that, you can always talk to customer support. A premium membership or custom membership might allow you to fetch the data you want. This link might get you started https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#support.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```py
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
api_key = "XXXX"
ts = TimeSeries(key = api_key,output_format = "pandas")
data, metadata = ts.get_intraday(symbol = "USDCAD",interval= "1min" , outputsize = "full")
print(data)
```

Here were the edits made to solve this.

1. You had a few syntax errors in your code sample.
2. "#" strings don't work as a parameter in the API key. For testing, use something like "XXXX"
3. The symbol has to be "USDCAD" not "USD/CAD"
4. Optional, but preferred: You should be using the `from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange` package to get currency pairs as opposed to the TimeSeries object.